# How can I point a domain name registered with network solutions to a subfolder in godaddy?

Tags: hosting, domain-name

Short story, I'm temporarily hosting a site on godaddy. I stuck the site in a subfolder (www.mysite.com/hostedsite). Now, I'm trying to get the domain name registered with network solutions to point to the subfolder (www.hostedsite.com point to www.mysite.com/hostedsite with masking).

So far the best I can figure to make this work is to buy domain forwarding from network solutions. Is there another way?

Comment: You cant do this on DNS. You need some kind of redirection/forwarding service.

Answer (score -1):

Forwarding with masking is only achievable by domain forwarding options provided by the registrars. Though, you can achieve it without Masking with the help of CNAME record as follows.

Create Sub-domain at GoDaddy like; ***hostedsite.mysite.com***
Add CNAME record in the DNS zone of www.mysite.com as follows;

***www.mysite.com***............CNAME..........***hostedsite.mysite.com***

Comment: Question is about redirecting the domain to a subdirectory of the same domain — not to a subdomain.